# Emulate PhotoShop's “Color Range” with Processing

Tags: java, image-processing, processing, reverse-engineering, photoshop

I'm trying to emulate Photoshop's "Color Range" using Processing. I've found some useful information about the algorithm here: [Emulate PhotoShop's "Color Range" algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986198/emulate-photoshops-color-range-algorithm)

But my problem is to implement it into a processing sketch, as I'm new to Java.

I've managed to do all the calculations but I don't know how to apply them, eg. I would like to change the saturation to the pixels in that range. How do I do that?

By the way here's my code (there's probably something wrong).

```
// Declaring variables
PImage img; 

void setup() {
  size(800,800);
  colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);

  //making the window resizable
//  if (frame != null) {
//    frame.setResizable(true);
//  }
  img = loadImage("scanned_texture.jpg");
}


void draw() {
  loadPixels();
  img.loadPixels();
  img.resize(800,800);

  //loop through every pixel
  for (int x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < img.height; y++ ) {

    // Calculate the 1D pixel location
    int loc = x + y*img.width;

    // Get the H,S,B values from image
    float h = hue   (img.pixels[loc]);
    float s = saturation (img.pixels[loc]);
    float b = brightness  (img.pixels[loc]);;


    float Point1hue = hue(27);
    float Point1sat = saturation(50);
    float Point1bright = brightness(80);

    float Point2hue = hue(57);
    float Point2sat = saturation(80);
    float Point2bright = brightness(100);

    //distance between colors
    float distance = sqrt(pow((Point2hue - Point1hue),2) + pow((Point2sat - Point1sat),2) + pow((Point2bright - Point1bright),2));
    float percentage = distance/sqrt((255)^2+(255)^2+(255)^2);

    color c = color(h,s,b);

    //change saturation based on color range
    if (c == percentage) {
      s = +50;
    }

    pixels[loc] = c;
  }
}
updatePixels();
}
```

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/6983/emulate-photoshop039s-color-range

Comment: Basically same remarks than those in the Processing forum: don't compare two floats, or a float with an integer. Here, you can do `if (c == it(percentage))` although comparing a "percentage" with a "color" seems strange...

Comment: Could you show results?