# how to directly convert between HSB color and Lab color in Processing / Java

Tags: java, colors, processing, lab-color-space, hsb

I am trying to convert back and forth between HSB color and Lab color in Processing / Java. I know that I can first convert HSB to RGB then to Lab, is it possible to directly convert from HSB to Lab? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Of course. You can simply write code for that.

Comment: is there any formula or code for converting available?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't provide a detailed answer.

There are fomulas of course: [HSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB), [CIE XYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Construction_of_the_CIE_XYZ_color_space_from_the_Wright%E2%80%93Guild_data) as you'll need for sRGB to CIE XYZ to then convert CIE XYZ to [L*a*b*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space#CIELAB%E2%80%93CIEXYZ_conversions). I'm sure you find implementations out

In terms of Java/Processing perhaps there is something already out there.
FWIW you can check out this older example of mine using [OpenFrameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583514/image-retrieval-system-by-colour-from-the-web-using-c-with-openframeworks/15721464#15721464).

[image: search images by dominant colour demo]

OpenFrameworks is to c++ as what Processing is to Java.
Hopefully you'll have no trouble swapping `struct` for `class` and `#define` for `float`, etc. The syntax is not that different in this case.

Comment: I tried to rewrite your code in Java, but was not able to obtain the same RGB value after converting from RGB to Lab then back to RGB, is there anything wrong in my rewriting? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62916036/1044679