# Processing how to get the nearest color from a Collection of colors

Tags: java, arrays, colors, processing

I have a `Collection of Integers` of Processing colors (it contains colors of images rescaled to 1x1 to get the "average" color). 
I have this thing that must retrieve me the nearest color of the array :

```java
public static int getNearestColor(Collection<Integer> colors, int color) {
    return colors.stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(i - color)))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("No value present"));
}
```

But when I do this, it returns me a color that is **way far** than the input, but the array contains some colors that are nearest than the input, **this** is my problem that I don't understand ?

Comment: programatically.. you want a number from an array.. which is either equal or nearest to the number of color parameter ? right ?

Comment: Yes and no, colors in processing are ints but strange ints, else my function would have worked

Comment: But your code returns the min diff and not the actual color that has the min diff.

Comment: oh
So what should I write so that it returns me the actual color that has the min diff ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry I don't understand how it should help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RGB color channels of a [`color()`](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html) are encoded in an `int`. You can extract the red, green and blue component of the color, by [`red()`](https://processing.org/reference/red_.html), [`green()`](https://processing.org/reference/red_.html) and [`blue()`](https://processing.org/reference/red_.html).
Treat the color channels as a 3 dimensional vector ([`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html)) and compute the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) of 2 color vectors, by [`dist()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_dist_.html). The color with the shortest "distance" is the "nearest" color:

In the following function the arguments `c1` and `c2` are colors of type `int`:

```java
float ColorDistance(int c1, int c2) {
    return PVector.dist(
        new PVector(red(c1), green(c1), blue(c1)), 
        new PVector(red(c2), green(c2), blue(c2)));
}
```

Find the "nearest" color, in a collection of colors, by finding the minimum floating point "distance" (`ColorDistance(i, color)`).

Comment: @Ayfri While the formula RGB distance formula is clean and correct, bare it's unlikely to find the perceptually closest color in RGB colour space. For that you may want to convert to L*a*b which is slightly [more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438063/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-ofcolors-in-openframeworks/15721504#15721504). Nice answer Rabbid76 (+1): clean and concise

Answer (score 0):

arrays in java don't have a stream method; perhaps you meant `Arrays.stream(colors)`. `IntStream` has no way to do a comparison other than on natural order. You can map to the difference (`abs(i - color)`) first, but now you've deleted the information you were looking for (the original color), so that won't work either. Let's box it. This results in the following code, which is exactly like your code, except this compiles and runs. I'll then also add a test case to make it a self-contained example:

```java
int[] colors = {1,4,5,9,12};
int target = 6;
int a = Arrays.stream(colors).boxed()
    .min(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(i - target)))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException());
System.out.println(a);
```

and, whoa nelly, '5' falls out, which is exactly what you want.

In other words, the intent of your code is fine, if it's not giving the right answer your inputs are not what you thought they are, or something else is wrong that cannot be gleaned from your paste.

May I suggest that if it is at all possible to put the question in a simple, self contained form (as this question clearly was, see the code snippet in this answer), that you do so? Often you'll answer your own questions that way :)

Comment: It's because I'm stupid, my function actually take `values()` from a `HashMap`, to simplify the problem I just put `int[]` but I didn't realized that the function cannot work with this, I'm so sorry :(
Can you modify your message ? I modified mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getNearestColor(int[] colors, int color) {
    int minDiff = IntStream.of(colors)
            .map(val -> Math.abs(val - color))
            .min()
            .getAsInt();

    OptionalInt num = IntStream.of(colors)
            .filter(val-> val==(color + minDiff))
            .findFirst();

    if(num.isPresent()){
        return color + minDiff;
    } else {
        return color - minDiff;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have changed the code flow.. But, This is returning the expected output !

Comment: I'm ! I'm stupid, my function actually take `values()` from a `HashMap`, to simplify the problem I just put `int[]` but I didn't realized that the function cannot work with this, I'm so sorry :(
Can you modify your message ? I modified mine.

Comment: Instead of just posting code, can you please explain what your code does and how it works, that way people can learn from it?